# Has the US ever been sanctioned by another country?

Tags: united-states, sanctions

The US and its Western allies use sanctions as an alternative to military action, or to express their displeasure. However, has the US ever been sanctioned? My search results only shows list of sanctions imposed by the US, not on the US.

Comment: RT just published the news that "Moscow has announced sanctions against US leadership, including Joe Biden, as well as the chiefs of the Pentagon and the CIA".

Comment: Wikipedia's [Economic sanctions against the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_sanctions_against_the_United_States) would seem like a good starting point?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Oh i forgot to mention that in the post, thats actually the first time i ever read the sentence (or phrase) "...has announced sanctions against US leadership"

Comment: @CDJB Oh I forgot trump's economic policies, maybe i set the bar too low...